# Uploading file to server problems

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload and save file in dir called `images` through a form. Form looks like this:

```
<form name="spremi" action="spremaj.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send" />
</form>
```

And `php` script looks like this:

```
if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```

Script always prints message "already exists". I know that questions like this were already asked, but none of the answers helped me. This code didn't work either on localhost, or web server. Thank you.

Comment: You should check what file is getting uploaded, otherwise one could upload a `.php` file or some other malicious file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html form you do not have a `file` parameter so your php  needs to accept `image` so change

```
if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
   echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}else
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to

```
if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
   echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}else
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```